# Converting pandas dataframe to dictionary and adding a common key-value pair

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

I have the foll. pandas dataframe (with datetime as index):

```
            name_col
datetime          
2016-11-01    0.00
2016-11-08    0.00
```

How do I convert this to a dictionary which looks like this:

```
[{field_id='1', date='2016-11-01', name_col=0.0}, {field_id='1', date='2016-11-08', name_col=0.0}]
```

Here I want to add a common key-value pair (field_id='1') for each item in the dictionary

I tried this:

```
df.to_dict()
```

but this does not help me add the common key-value pair (field_id='1') and also does not give the format I want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `assign` to clean up syntax

```
df.assign(field_id=1).reset_index().to_dict('records')

[{'datetime': '2016-11-01', 'field_id': 1, 'name_col': 0.0},
 {'datetime': '2016-11-08', 'field_id': 1, 'name_col': 0.0}]
```

Answer (score 3):

one possible way is to add a column and then convert to dict like:

```
In [1]: import pandas as pd

In [2]: data = [["2016-11-01",0.00], ["2016-11-08",0.00]]

In [3]: df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=["datetime", "name_col"])

In [4]: df["field_id"] = 1

In [5]: df
Out[5]:
     datetime  name_col  field_id
0  2016-11-01       0.0         1
1  2016-11-08       0.0         1

In [6]: df.to_dict(orient="record")
Out[6]:
[{'datetime': '2016-11-01', 'field_id': 1, 'name_col': 0.0},
 {'datetime': '2016-11-08', 'field_id': 1, 'name_col': 0.0}]
```